# Bound on the number of hidden nodes for multilayer perceptron with a single hidden layer

Tags: ne.neural-evol

The universal approximation theorem states that:

---

Let $\phi(·)$ be a nonconstant, bounded, and monotonically-increasing continuous function. Let $I_m$ denote the m-dimensional unit hypercube $[0,1]^m$. The space of continuous functions on $I_m$ is denoted by $C(I_m)$. Then, given any function $f ∈ C(I_m)$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exist an integer $N$ and real constants $\alpha_i,b_i \in \Re$, $w_i ∈ \Re^m$, where $i = 1, \dots , N$ such that we may define:

$$
    F( x ) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \alpha_i \phi \left( w_i^T x + b_i\right) 
$$

as an approximate realization of the function f where f is independent of $\phi$; that is,

$$
    | F( x ) - f ( x ) | < \epsilon 
$$

for all $x \in I_m$. In other words, functions of the form $F(x)$ are dense in $C(I_m)$.

---

Is there a bound on $\epsilon$ in terms of $N$?